# Display several copies of the same JTable with rowHeaders in the same window

Tags: java

I have one Java program that displays one copy of the JTable with rowHeaders that I want.  I have another program comprised of two Java files.  The 1st file contains (I hope), the code to build the JTable with rowHeaders.  The 2nd file calls the 1st file to get copies of the JTable to add to the main window.  I will try to attach the three files.  Thanks in advance for any help.

This file will display the JTable with rowHeaders that I need copies of.

```
    class RowHeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

RowHeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    setOpaque(true);
    setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
    setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    setForeground(header.getForeground());
    setBackground(header.getBackground());
    setFont(header.getFont());
}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                    int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    return this;
}
```

}

public class JTable_wRowHdrs extends JFrame {

```
static String rowHdrs[] = { "CL", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "TL", "AN" };
static String colHdrs[] = {  "0",  "1",  "2",  "3", "TL"             };
static int  colWidths[] = {   16,   16,   16,   16,  30              };

static JList  rowHeader;
static JList  colHeader;

static Dimension tSize  = new Dimension(170, 200);  // this is window size

public JTable_wRowHdrs() {                          // constructor
    super("File: JTable_wRowHdrs");                 // set titleBar text
    setSize(tSize);                                 // if cmt'd out, get titleBar ONLY

    ListModel rm = new AbstractListModel() {        // 'rm' for rowModel
        public int    getSize()               { return  rowHdrs.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int index) { return  rowHdrs[index]; }
    };
    ListModel cm = new AbstractListModel() {        // 'cm' for columnModel
        public int    getSize()               { return  colHdrs.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int index) { return  colHdrs[index]; }
    };

    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(colHdrs, rm.getSize());
    JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

//      table.setPreferredSize(tSize);      // if cmt'd out, get scrollBars ONLY when the
                                            // * actual JTable not completely visible
                                            // if NOT cmt'd out, get scrollBars ONLY when
                                            // * the "white area" not completely visible

```
    rowHeader = new JList(rm);
    rowHeader.setFixedCellWidth(25);                // this works

    rowHeader.setFixedCellHeight(table.getRowHeight());
    rowHeader.setCellRenderer(new RowHeaderRenderer(table));

    colHeader = new JList(cm);                      // The column hdr widths match their
```

//      colHeader.setFixedCellWidth(35);                // * column widths, as they should.

```
    for (int i = 0;  i < colHdrs.length;  i++) {
        TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        column.setMinWidth(      colWidths[i]);
        column.setMaxWidth(      colWidths[i]);
        column.setPreferredWidth(colWidths[i]);
    }   

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    scroll.setRowHeaderView(rowHeader);             // REQ'D to show row headers!
    scroll.setColumnHeaderView(colHeader);          // doesn't seem to help or hurt
    getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTable_wRowHdrs frame = new JTable_wRowHdrs();

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

This program builds the window I want and gets 3 instances of 
the JTable I want from the next class file.

```
    public class JTables3wRowHdrs extends JFrame {

static  int     panels     = 3;
static  int     dataTables = 3;
static  int     WW = 0, CC = 1, EE = 2;

static  JTable[]        jTable = new JTable[     dataTables];
static  JScrollPane[]   jSPane = new JScrollPane[dataTables];
static  JPanel[]        jPanel = new JPanel[     panels];


protected void frameInit() {
    int     i;

    super.frameInit();
    setTitle("_3Tables_wRowHdrs");
    setSize(750, 300);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setVisible(true);

    setupScrollPanes();                     // a JScrollPane for each custom JTable
    setupPanels();                          // a JPanel for each BorderLayout area 

    getContentPane().add(jSPane[WW], BorderLayout.WEST);    // add West panel  to area WEST
    getContentPane().add(jSPane[CC], BorderLayout.CENTER);  // *   Center      to      CENTER
    getContentPane().add(jSPane[EE], BorderLayout.EAST);    // *   East        to      EAST
```

//      add(jPanel[WW], BorderLayout.WEST);     // add West panel  to area WEST
//      add(jPanel[CC], BorderLayout.CENTER);   // *   Center      to      CENTER
//      add(jPanel[EE], BorderLayout.EAST);     // *   East        to      EAST

```
}

public static void setupScrollPanes() {
    for (int i = 0;  i < dataTables;  i++) {
        jTable[i] = new JTable_forJTables3();

        jSPane[i] = new JScrollPane(jTable[i]);
        jSPane[i].setRowHeaderView(   JTable_forJTables3.rowHeader);  // REQ'D for row headers!
        jSPane[i].setColumnHeaderView(JTable_forJTables3.colHeader);  // does anything?

        jSPane[i].setMinimumSize(  new Dimension(190, 215));    // get 3 empty 189,214 
        jSPane[i].setMaximumSize(  new Dimension(190, 215));    // * rectangles
        jSPane[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190, 215));
    }
}

public static void setupPanels() {
    for (int i = 0;  i < dataTables;  i++) {
        jPanel[i] = new JPanel();
        jPanel[i].add(jSPane[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JTables3wRowHdrs frame = new JTables3wRowHdrs();

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

This file should provide an instance of the JTable I want 
to the Java code above.

```
    class RowHeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

RowHeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    setOpaque(true);
    setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
    setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    setForeground(header.getForeground());
    setBackground(header.getBackground());
    setFont(header.getFont());
}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                    int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    return this;
}
```

}

public class JTable_forJTables3 extends JTable {

```
static String rowHdrs[] = { "CL", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "TL", "AN" };
static String colHdrs[] = {  "0",  "1",  "2",  "3", "TL"             };
static int  colWidths[] = {   16,   16,   16,   16,  30              };

static JList  rowHeader;
static JList  colHeader;

static Dimension tSize  = new Dimension(170, 200);  // this is window size

public JTable_forJTables3() {                       // constructor
    super();                                        // 
    setSize(tSize);                                 // if cmt'd out, get titleBar ONLY

    ListModel rm = new AbstractListModel() {        // 'rm' for rowModel
        public int    getSize()               { return  rowHdrs.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int index) { return  rowHdrs[index]; }
    };
    ListModel cm = new AbstractListModel() {        // 'cm' for columnModel
        public int    getSize()               { return  colHdrs.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int index) { return  colHdrs[index]; }
    };

    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(colHdrs, rm.getSize());
    JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

//      table.setPreferredSize(tSize);      // if cmt'd out, get scrollBars ONLY when the
                                            // * actual JTable not completely visible
                                            // if NOT cmt'd out, get scrollBars ONLY when
                                            // * the "white area" not completely visible

```
    JList rowHeader = new JList(rm);
    rowHeader.setFixedCellWidth(25);                // this works

    rowHeader.setFixedCellHeight(table.getRowHeight());
    rowHeader.setCellRenderer(new RowHeaderRenderer(table));

    JList colHeader = new JList(cm);                // The column hdr widths match their
```

//      colHeader.setFixedCellWidth(35);                // * column widths, as they should.

```
    for (int i = 0;  i < colHdrs.length;  i++) {
        TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        column.setMinWidth(      colWidths[i]);
        column.setMaxWidth(      colWidths[i]);
        column.setPreferredWidth(colWidths[i]);
    }   
}
```

}

The code above seems close to working, but is not quite
there yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
TIA, Key

Comment: My question above is clearly a MESS.  Sorry.  Is it possible to enter 3 source files in a question, and if so, how?

Comment: How do I cancel or withdraw a question?  This is is not answer-able.